# Can javascript recognize mouse movements?

Tags: javascript, python, pyautogui

I would like to know if there is a way to "monitor" mouse movements. I'm developing automation in python and I don't know if there's a way for javascript to recognize what I'm planning to do.
I think teleporting the mouse pointer could give some hint of automation.
I think disguising the movement could be an option.
I plan to use Pyautogui, Selenium wouldn't run what I need.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html Code

```
<div onmousemove="myFunction(event)"></div>
```

Js code

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can detect mouse movement by listening for the [`mousemove` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) and get the coordinates of the pointer with [`MouseEvent.pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) and [`MouseEvent.pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY):

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  const xCoordinate = e.pageX;
  const yCoordinate = e.pageY;
  output.innerHTML = `x: ${xCoordinate}, y: ${yCoordinate}`
})
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```